# Inputting string using (gets.chomp) and producing a histogram

Tags: ruby

I'm having struggles understanding ruby. I wish to have a program in which a user can input a set of text and it come back with asterisks. So far I was able to do it via a .txt file. Can anyone explain where I went wrong? I am struggling with ruby a lot.

[Image of outcome when I run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIqOi.png)

```
print "Please enter any length of text:"
user_input = String(gets.chomp)
h = Hash.new
f = user_input
f.each_line { |line|
  letters = line.split(//)
  letters.each { |w|
    if h.has_key?(w)
      h[w] = h[w] + 1
    else
      h[w] = 1
    end
  }
}

# sort the hash by
h.sort{|a,b| a[1]<=>b[1]}.each { |elem|
  puts "\"#{elem[0]}\": " + '*' * elem[1]
}
```

Error message I encountered

```
Undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: I recommend you to read this.  https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Tutorial/part_02/user_input.html

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: I recieve the error 
<br>
`ndefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 0):

In the script runner of Atom where you are currently running your Ruby program, you can not read from standard input using `gets`. It appears that the [script-runner package](https://atom.io/packages/script-runner) can extend this to provide a real terminal to the script where you can then also use STDIN.

Alternatively, you could also run your program from a real console. For that, you have run it from a command line window, e.g. with `ruby name_of_program.rb` instead of starting it from Atom.

Comment: Discovered issue, was to do with file pathway

Answer (score 0):

The `gets` method must be called alone. Try it in your second line:

```
user_input = gets.chomp
```

without `String`.

I hope it useful for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as intended. You went wrong by running the code in your text editor instead of through the console. The `Kernal#gets` method requires user input, which would need to be *mocked* in order to run within your text-editor. Because your *editor* is returning `nil` instead of user input in string format, the `chomp` method is raising your `NoMethodError`.

Essentially your code is fine, but your are trying to run it in a limited environment. As a beginner, if your code requires user input, it's easier to test the code by running your ruby file through the console/terminal with `ruby <filename.rb>`.